# How can I print the steps the algorithm takes to find the result (dijkstra's algorithm)?

Tags: python, dijkstra

So I have this dijkstra's algorithm code,that calculates the shortest distance between from the starting node to every other. Except for the result, I want the algorithm to also print the steps it made to find the solution. How can this be done?

```
nodes = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')

distances = {
 '1': {'1': 0, '2': int(input('enter distance from 1 to 2')), '4': int(input('enter distance from 1 to 4'))},
'2': {'2': 0, '1': int(input('enter distance from 2 to 1')), '3':  int(input('enter distance from 2 to 3')), '4' : int(input('enter distance from 2 to 4')), '5':  int(input('enter distance from 2 to 5'))},
'3': {'3': 0, '2': int(input('enter distance from 3 to 2')), '4': int(input('enter distance from 3 to 4')), '5': int(input('enter distance from 3 to 5')), '6':int(input('enter distance from 3 to 6'))},
'4': {'4': 0, '1': int(input('enter distance from 4 to 1')), '2':int(input('enter distance from 4 to 2')), '3':int(input('enter distance from 4 to 3')), '5':int(input('enter distance from 4 to 5'))},
'5': {'5': 0, '3': int(input('enter distance from 5 to 3')), '4': int(input('enter distance from 5 to 4')), '2':int(input('enter distance from 5 to 2')), '6':int(input('enter distance from 5 to 6'))},
'6': {'6': 0, '3': int(input('enter distance from 6 to 3')), '5': int(input('enter distance from 6 to 5')), }

}
a=input('enter current')
unvisited = {node: None for node in nodes} #using None as +inf
visited = {}
current = a
currentDistance = 0
unvisited[current] = currentDistance 

while True:
for neighbour, distance in distances[current].items():
    if neighbour not in unvisited: continue
    newDistance = currentDistance + distance
    if unvisited[neighbour] is None or unvisited[neighbour] > newDistance:
        unvisited[neighbour] = newDistance
visited[current] = currentDistance
del unvisited[current]
if not unvisited: break
candidates = [node for node in unvisited.items() if node[1]]
current, currentDistance = sorted(candidates, key = lambda x: x[1])[0]

print(visited)
```

Comment: sample input missing; wrong indentation

Comment: In order _to also print the steps_ you'd have to decide what you consider a step. In the simplest case, move the `print(visited)` into the loop.